# Android Spinner in AlertDialog doesn't select option

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

I have a `Spinner` inside of an `AlertDialog`, but whenever I select a value inside the spinner, it doesn't show once the spinner is closed. 
My `onItemSelected` doesn't log anything to the console either (I have confirmed the log method isn't the broken method). The nested `runOnUiThread` is an attempt at fixing this issue, although it hasn't worked.

```
Spinner selector = new Spinner(XActivity.this);
                                          selector.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                            selector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
                                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void run() {
                                                            X.getInstance().log("Selected item : " + adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                                                }
                                            });

                                            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(RegisterActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, LIST);
                                            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                            selector.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                                            selector.setPrompt("*removed*");
                                            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(XActivity.this);
                                            dialogBuilder.setView(selector);

                                            dialogBuilder.setTitle("*removed*");
                                            dialogBuilder.setMessage("*removed*");
                                            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                                    String selected = String.valueOf(selector.getSelectedItem());
                                                    X.getInstance().log("User selected " + selected + "");
                                                }
                                            });
                                            dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Select Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                                    // TODO                                                    }
                                            });
                                            dialogBuilder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                                                    // TODO
                                                }
                                            });
                                            AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                                            b.show();
```

Edit: Screenshots

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show screenshot?

Comment: @TruongHieu Screenshots added. That's what it looks like, and once I tap "Adventure" it essentially closes the spinner and nothing is selected.

Comment: I just checked your code, I replaced your X.getInstance().log() with simple Log.d() and simplified by cutting out your dialogBuilder.setButtons = it worked fine

Comment: @TWL Odd. My X.getInstance().log() calls log.d, and switching it out with Log.d() has no effect on anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying your code and making some minor/simplifying adjustments, I found nothing unusual with it, works fine!

```
            Spinner selector = new Spinner(MainActivity.this);
            selector.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            selector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG, adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    new String[]{"a","b","c"});
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            selector.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialogBuilder.setView(selector);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("title");
            dialogBuilder.setMessage("message");
            AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
            b.show();
```

My logs show "a", "b", "c" as I select them.

Please trace your steps and test as you re-build my code back up to match yours.

EDIT:

```
List<String> LIST = new ArrayList<>();
LIST.add("a");
LIST.add("b");
LIST.add("c");
```

And using `LIST` instead of `new String[]{}` also worked fine.

Comment: Looks like using my List<String> over a String[] causes my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Using List<String> shouldn't cause any issues, I just tried that as well...